# React interaction between children component: refs vs callback as props

Tags: reactjs

While studying React, I found an example in which a button, when clicked, must give focus to an input text. Both input and button are distinct components.

I see two ways of accomplishing that:

- Using Ref with input text and passing it down to the button;
- Create a function/method inside the parent component (Parent) and pass it to the button so that it will call it back when clicked. Pass a prop (e.g. focus: true/false) to the input text and attribute a Parent state to it. When the button call the Parent function back, it updates the Parent state, which result in changing the input prop from false to true (for example).

While both approaches give the same result, the second one seems better to me (in inspite of needing more code) because it decouples the children components. The first approach requires less code, but passes details of the input to the button, harming the button reuse.

Is there any implications (objective - not a matter of preference) of using the first/second approach not mentioned by me?

Comment: Not sure I follow what the question is in here. In terms of how to write it, the second option is generally the more preferred way to do it

Comment: Hello, Manuela. Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is focused on narrowed technical question that can get definite answer and is not suitable for opinion-based discussions. I think your question will be closed shortly as opinion-based. Cannot advice any particular resource for discussion like that(reddit.com? medium.com? dev.to?). Try searching for "react best practices", there should be a bunch of articles that may help you.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that. I'll be more cautious in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Focus method with ref should work nicely.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus

You can always pass props to the `onClick` event of your reusable button.